# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement en-core-web-sm==3.5.0

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip, nlp, spacy

I'm trying to upload my flask NLP app into the google cloud console. For the application, I'm using spacy and en_core_web_sm libraries.When I try to deploy the app using

```
 gcloud app deploy
```

I get the below error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement en-core-web-sm==3.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: none)
Step #2: ERROR: No matching distribution found for en-core-web-sm==3.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
Step #2: WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.2; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
Step #2: You should consider upgrading via the '/env/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Step #2: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
Finished Step #2
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:08c5443ff4f8ba85c2114576bb9167c4de0bf658818aea536d3456e8d0e134cd" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
Step #2: 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed. 
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build f3dbc963-ba57-4019-bf30-f33ddc6cfcb0 status: FAILURE
An unexpected error occurred. Refer to build logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/f3dbc963-ba57-4019-bf30-f33ddc6cfcb0?project=327998514658
Full build logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/f3dbc963-ba57-4019-bf30-f33ddc6cfcb0?project=327998514658
```

below is my requirements.txt file

```
Flask==2.0.3
gunicorn==20.1.0
en-core-web-sm==3.5.0
nltk==3.8.1
spacy==3.5.0
```

below is my python version

```
kavishka_2019399@cloudshell:~/signspeak02 (sign-speak-02)$ python --version
Python 3.9.2
```

p.s: I got the same error when trying to deploy the app into aws ec2.

Comment: Because there is no such package? https://pypi.org/project/en-core-web-sm/

Comment: but it works in my local machine :(( https://spacy.io/models/en

Comment: Notice how that package is installed: `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`. That is a non-standard installation method that might not be supported but I am not sure.

Comment: that is whats said in the documentation of spacy. I tried to pip install aswell... no luck :(

Comment: See: https://spacy.io/usage/models#production